# Set callback along with its parameters and invoke the callback later

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple class `Foo` that allows the user of this class to set a callback and later run it three times.

This is how I am solving the problem.

```
# API code
class Foo:
    def set_handler(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        self.callback = callback
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run_three_times(self):
        for i in range(3):
            return self.callback(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

# User of the API code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def myfunc(a, b, c='foo', d='bar'):
        print(a, b, c, d)

    foo = Foo()
    foo.set_handler(myfunc, 'arg1', 'arg2', c='arg3', d='arg4')
    foo.run_three_times()
```

So you see that in the `foo.set_handler` call I am passing the callback along with its parameters. When `foo.run_three_times` is called, this method carefully invokes the callback with the parameters I had passed earlier.

Is this the right way to do this thing? Isn't it possible to pass `myfunc('arg1', 'arg2', c='arg3', d='arg4')` in a more direct manner? Something like passing only one object that encapsulates the callback along with its arguments as a single function?

This is what I am looking for expressed in Python-pseudocode.

```
class Foo:
    def set_handler(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def run_three_times(self):
        for i in range(3):
            return self.callback()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def myfunc(a, b, c='foo', d='bar'):
        print(a, b, c, d)

    foo = Foo()
    mycallback = reference to myfunc('arg1', 'arg2', c='arg3', d='arg4')
    foo.set_handler(mycallback)
    foo.run_three_times()
```

Comment: `functools.partial` permits to do this. See the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flesh out @doukremt's comment, here is an example using [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> my_list = partial(list, 'Hello world!')
>>> my_list
<functools.partial object at 0x10ce98838>
>>> my_list()
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
```

See the documentation link above for more information.

Comment: @trsoten Damn! You got there before me! +1.